# Regex to match groups and join with new character to create csv

Tags: regex, csv

Consider the following strings:

```
"Teddy     45.  45. stuff to ignore"
"Gone     100.   6. stuff to ignore"
"Home       1. 200. stuff to ignore"
```

Is there a regex that could produce the following:

```
"Teddy,45,45"
"Gone,100,6"
"Home,1,200"
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex to match is: `^"([a-z]+)\s+(\d+)\.\s+(\d+).+` with `g`, `m` and `i` options.

The regex to substitute is: `"\1,\2,\3"`.

For a working example see https://regex101.com/r/5Tf0DD/1